# PHP constructors without parameters or executable code

Tags: php, singleton

While learning about design patterns I have come across the singleton pattern:

```
class Singleton
{
    private static $instance = null;

    private function __construct()
    {
    }

    public static function getInstance()
    {
        if (self::$instance === null) {
            self::$instance = new self();
        }

        return self::$instance;
    }
}
```

I'm having a hard time understanding what the constructor does in this circumstance. There isn't any code being executed between the braces? How does this work? Thanks.

Comment: @Akintunde I don't think he's asking how the construct works.

Comment: FYI, singleton is actually an anti-pattern, that is used to create global state. The only practical use of this patter is as first step in refactoring a codebase, where you want to move from included-oriented programming to object-oriented programming. A proper OOP code does not contain this anti-pattern.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The constructor marked `private` is used to avoid the instantiation of the singleton class, so there is always only a single one.

For example we cannot do this:

```
$singleton = new Singleton();
```

It yields:

> Fatal error: Call to private Singleton::__construct() from invalid context

You must fetch the singleton:

```
$singleton = Singleton::getInstance();
```

Comment: thanks, it makes much more sense to me now. Is this considered a valid use of the construct function or is this viewed as somewhat of a "hack" since there isn't anything actually being constructed?

Comment: It's a valid use of constructor, because we can make some initialization in it, it's also a hach to restrict the number of instances that are being create to a single instance that is shared.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: Thanks for making that clear. Your english seems fine!

Answer (score 0):

As the constructor is marked as `private`, it can only be called from within the class.  This allows the method `getInstance` to create a new instance-

```
self::$instance = new self();
```

But (as pointed out) if you tried to create an instance of this class in your own code - it will give an error as you can't call the `private` constructor.

This allows a class to restrict how instances of this object are created and therefore in this case limit it to 1 copy.